# Spring Security OAuth Maven build failed

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security-oauth2

I deleted my `~/.m2/repository` and did a `mvn clean install -P bootstrap` on commit `#371aad08ac93efa2` (master) cloned from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth. It could not get pass javadoc "phase" and threw up with. I used JDK 1.7.0_65 in Linux and Windows. I could compile the project with my old `~/.m2/repository` before.

What am I missing here? Thanks

```
....
[ERROR] javadoc: warning - Class Autowired not found.
[ERROR] javadoc: warning - Class Autowired not found.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '~/workspace/spring-security-oauth/spring-security-oauth/target/apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Works for me. What version of Maven are you using?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-12T04:58:10+08:00)

Comment: Probably worth trying an older one (I use "3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)").

Comment: I deleted my .m2/repostory and built with Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 21:51:28+0800). still failed at javadoc lifecycle

Comment: Still works for me, sorry. Do you have a weird network? Proxy?

Comment: I checked my network settings and ran `mvn compile`. it worked. I even had my colleague to checkout clean and build with Maven 3.2.1 but failed. We build with -X option. I could not find any "obvious" anomaly with javadoc plugin. Any hint as to where I can find problem lurking in the debug log?

Comment: What version of the javadoc plugin are you getting?

Comment: It used `maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10:jar`. In another trial, I added artifactId and version tags for the javadoc plugin i.e.        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>

Comment: Try now (I nailed it to 2.9.1).

Comment: Yes, you nailed it :) Any idea why 2.10 screwed up?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding version tag to 2.9.1 to maven-javadoc-plugin in `<project_root>/pom.xml` line 187 following @DaveSyer solution i.e.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <!-- added for completeness -->
<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9.1</version> <!-- fix version instead of getting the latest version, 2.10 -->
```